# Configure smart indent rules in VIM

Tags: vim, indentation, auto-indent

I am writing Fortran code in VIM, and I would like to know how I can edit/define my own rules for the smart indentation. For example, I learned that adding the line

```
let fortran_do_enddo=1
```

to my `vimrc` file will make VIM indent everything between `do` and `enddo` commands (it did not do this previously). I have not, however, been able to find a guide explaining how I can make other such rules for different situations.

Specifically, VIM currently indents the line after the `program myprogram` statement, and I would like to disable that feature.

Comment: Check whether FORTRAN.vim exists under /use/share/vim/vim74/   vim74 is my version. That should indent as per FORTRAN syntax. You can check for such syntax lines like you have given.